# Push to array just read second index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

i have problem to convert array to another array. When i try to push in new array, it just add second index.

Here is my Array :

```
var emailAddr = [
    {
        customerID : "C20121121221327_249",
        email : "fanjavaid@gmails.com",
        files : [
            "201409011141106_082895250262",
            "201410011171208_082895250262"
        ]
    },
    {
        customerID : "C20121121221327_300",
        email : "fandi.java@gmail.com",
        files : [
            "201409011141106_xxx",
        ]
    }
];
```

Here my code to create new array :

```
var penampungan = [];
for (var i = 0; i < emailAddr.length; i++) {
    var data = {
        customerID : emailAddr[i].customerID,
        email : emailAddr[i].email
    };

    for (var j = 0; j < emailAddr[i].files.length; j++) {        
        data['master'] = emailAddr[i].files[j] + ".pdf";
        data['detail'] = emailAddr[i].files[j] + "_detail.pdf";

        penampungan.push(data);
    }
}

console.log(penampungan);
```

My expected result is like this :

```
var newArray = [
    {
        customerID : "C20121121221327_249",
        email : "fanjavaid@gmail.com",
        master : "201409011141106_082895250262.pdf",
        detail : "201409011141106_082895250262_detail.pdf"
    },
    {
        customerID : "C20121121221327_249",
        email : "fanjavaid@gmail.com",
        master : "201410011171208_082895250262.pdf",
        detail : "201410011171208_082895250262_detail.pdf"
    },
    {
        customerID : "C20121121221327_300",
        email : "fandi.java@gmail.com",
        master : "201409011141106_xxx.pdf",
        detail : "201409011141106_xxx_detail.pdf"
    }
];
```

How to create that?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you need to unfold your files field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `data` creation to the inner loop

```
var penampungan = [];
for (var i = 0; i < emailAddr.length; i++) {       
    for (var j = 0; j < emailAddr[i].files.length; j++) {
        var data = {
             customerID : emailAddr[i].customerID,
             email : emailAddr[i].email
        };        
        data['master'] = emailAddr[i].files[j] + ".pdf";
        data['detail'] = emailAddr[i].files[j] + "_detail.pdf";

        penampungan.push(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: very minor, but you could of course make it all consistent and set `master` and `detail` in the `data = {}` too

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var penampungan = [];
for (var i = 0; i < emailAddr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < emailAddr[i].files.length; j++) {
        var data = {};
        data.customerID = emailAddr[i].customerID,
        data.email = emailAddr[i].email
        data.master = emailAddr[i].files[j] + ".pdf";
        data.detail= emailAddr[i].files[j] + "_detail.pdf";
        penampungan.push(data);
    }
}
console.log(penampungan);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not create a class? It would organize the data in each element of your array for you and reduce the amount of code needed to be parsed. May I suggest something like:

```
function Info (customerID, email, files) {
    this.customerID = customerID;
    this.email = email;
    this.files = files;
    this.penampungan = function () {
        var newObjects = new Array (files.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            newObjects [i] = {
                customerID : this.customerID,
                email : this.email,
                master : files [i] + ".pdf",
                detail : files [i] + "_detail.pdf",
            };
        }
    return newObjects;
    }
}
```

Now make a for statement that takes an Info array and loads the penampungan objects into a new array.